# Configuration Spring - Kafka for many clusters Kafka? What is best solution?

Tags: spring-kafka

I see people duplicating code to configure kafka for each cluster :(

Is it really necessary to configure Consumer Factory and Producer Factory with different settings every time? And do not use Spring Boot Kafka starter in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use similar properties for each cluster, you can override the `bootstrap.servers` property for each `@KafkaListener` and/or create multiple `@KafkaTemplate`s with the same override.

Then, the same factories can be used.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-properties

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "group", properties = {
    "max.poll.interval.ms:60000",
    ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG + "=100"
})
```

```java
/**
 * Create an instance using the supplied producer factory and properties, with
 * autoFlush false. If the configOverrides is not null or empty, a new
 * {@link DefaultKafkaProducerFactory} will be created with merged producer properties
 * with the overrides being applied after the supplied factory's properties.
 * @param producerFactory the producer factory.
 * @param configOverrides producer configuration properties to override.
 * @since 2.5
 */
public KafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory, @Nullable Map<String, Object> configOverrides) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot auto-configuration is by convention for the common microservices use-case: one thing, but simple and clear.

What you are asking is out of Spring Boot scope: the properties configuration is applied only for one `ConsumerFactory` and one `ProducerFactory`. As long as you need to connect to different clusters you are on your own. Having a custom `ConsumerFactory` bean will lead Spring Boot auto-configuration to back off.

You probably can look into a child `ApplicationContext` configuration with its own provided set of properties. But will it be easier to just have custom configuration for each cluster as you would do without Spring Boot with just a plain Apache Kafka client?

I have no idea if there is some federation solution for Apache Kafka. But that's still out of Spring for Apache Kafka and Spring Boot scope.

Comment: You can use Boot's auto configured factories and just override the `bootstrap.servers` for individual components.